# My .jar file won't open MP3 files (I'm using Jlayer - JZoom library)

Tags: java, audio, jar, mp3, jlayer

I did this small Java project that in it's turn opens different MP3 files. For that I downloaded the JLayer 1.0.1 library and added it to my project. I also added the MP3 files to a package on my project -as well as some JPG images- so as to obtain them from there, and I'm using a hashmap (mapa) and this method to get them:

```
public static String consiguePath (int i) {


return AppUtils.class.getClass().getResource("/Movimiento/" + mapa.get(i)).getPath();

}
```

so as to avoid absolute paths.

When I open an MP3 file I do this:

```
try {
                            File archivo = new File(AppUtils.consiguePath(12));
                            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(archivo);
                            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                            try {
                                Player player = new Player(bis);
                                player.play();
                            } catch (JavaLayerException jle) {
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        }
```

The whole thing runs perfectly in NetBeans, but when I build a .jar file and execute it it runs well but it won't open the MP3 files. What called my attention is that it doesn't have trouble in opening the JPG files that are on the same package.

After generating the .jar I checked the MyProject/build/classes/Movimiento folder and all of the MP3 files were actually there, so I don't know what may be happening.

I've seen others had this problem before but I haven't seen any satisfactory answer yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Return the resulting `URL` of `AppUtils.class.getClass().getResource` and not a `String` file, the resources are embedded within your jar file and can no longer to accessed using `File`

Comment: Amazing, it worked! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `consiguePath` to return the resulting `URL` from `getResource`

```
public static URL consiguePath(int i) {

    return AppUtils.class.getClass().getResource("/Movimiento/" + mapa.get(i));

}
```

And then use it's `InputStream` to pass to the `Player`

```
try {
    URL url = AppUtils.consiguePath(12);
    Player player = new Player(url.openStream());
    player.play();
} catch (JavaLayerException | IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Equally, you could just use `Class#getResourceAsStream`

Resources are packaged into your Jar file and can no longer be treated as `File`s